# mysql I don´t understand the if meaning here

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $sql = "select u.Id, u.username, u.email, (NOW()-u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference, u.IP, 
          f.providerId, f.requestId, f.status, u.port 
       from friends f
       left join users u on 
          u.Id = if ( f.providerId = ".$userId.", f.requestId, f.providerId ) 
       where (f.providerId = ".$userId." and f.status=".USER_APPROVED.")  or 
           f.requestId = ".$userId." ORDER BY u.username ASC";
```

I don´t understand the if meaning here , being used with where

```
// providerId and requestId is Id of  a friend pair,
// providerId is the Id of making first friend request
// requestId is the Id of the friend approved the friend request made by providerId

// fetching friends, 
// left join expression is a bit different, 
//  it is required to fetch the friend, not the users itself
```

anyone can explain it for me ? thanx

Comment: IF is not used “with WHERE” there, but in the ON clause of the join. And what don’t you understand about it? You can read up on how IF works in the manual, so what question does that still leave open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just make the Join between *Friends* and *Users* be made by requestId only if the condition `f.providerId = ".$userId."` is true. If not, the join is made by providerId.

I see that `$userId` is a php variable you're passing to the query so maybe the idea is to check wether the active user is a provider and then get the row thats associated with the request instead of the provider in the *Friends* table.

Heres doc on If function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if